# Switching from בוֹ to בָהּ in Shabbat blessing

Tags: shabbat, grammar-dikduk, prayer-book, nusach-ashkenaz

During Shabbat, it is a [common](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/21777/15256) [Ashkenazi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/79983/15256) [practice](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31136/15256) to say three different versions of the *Retzei* blessing – *vah, vo* and *vam* (Magein Avraham to [Orach Chayim 268:3](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%A1%D7%97_%D7%92) citing [Sheyarei Keneset haGedolah](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42559&pgnum=101)). But if we look at old manuscripts and books like the [Siddur Rav Amram Gaon](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43020&pgnum=58) or the [Machzor Vitry](https://www.nli.org.il/en/discover/manuscripts/hebrew-manuscripts/viewerpage?vid=MANUSCRIPTS#d=%5B%5BPNX_MANUSCRIPTS990001218850205171-1,FL34995596%5D%5D), we find וְיִשְׂמְחוּ בְךָ כָּל יִשְׂרָאֵל אוֹהֲבֵי שְׁמֶךָ, which is close to the version that the Yekkes still use. The [Beiurei haTefillah](https://www.beureihatefila.com/files/2009-08-07_Tefila_Newsletter.pdf) site cites the [Seifer haMinhagim](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=8913&pgnum=10), who says that joy is a concept rather related to festivals, so based on experts he had heard he suggested the version וְיָנוּחוּ **בוֹ** יִשְׂרָאֵל מְקַדְּשֵׁי שְׁמֶךָ to be used. This is how it is in the [Bach](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%98%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%A1%D7%97) or in the *siddur* of the [Shelah](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22373&pgnum=395) or [R' Emden](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19725&pgnum=670), even in the controversial prayer book of [Solomon Hanau](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20697&pgnum=72). How come that R' Heidenheim has בָהּ *(vah)* in all three instances even in the [earliest editions](https://www.nli.org.il/en/books/NNL_ALEPH990025049110205171/NLI) (p. 129)? [Baer](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42897&pgnum=218) later argued that this was the grammatically correct form, but do they have any earlier Ashkenazi references supporting their claim?